# Defining Target based on two column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I was facing some issue solving the following problem.

I have the following dataframe:

```
SoldDate       CountSoldperMonth
2019-06-01          20
                    5
                    10
                    12
                    33
                    16
                    50
                    27

2019-05-01          2
                    5
                    11
                    13

2019-04-01          32
                    35
                    39
                    42
                    47
                    55
                    61
                    80
```

I need to add a Target column such that for the top 5 values in 'CountSoldperMonth' for a particular SoldDate, target should be 1 else 0. If the number of rows in 'CountSoldperMonth' for a particular 'SoldDate' is less than 5 then only the row with highest count will be marked as 1 in the Target and rest as 0. The resulting dataframe should look as below.

```
SoldDate       CountSoldperMonth      Target
2019-06-01          20                  1
                    5                   0
                    10                  0
                    12                  0
                    33                  1
                    16                  1
                    50                  1
                    27                  1

2019-05-01          2                   0
                    5                   0
                    11                  0
                    13                  1

2019-04-01          32                  0
                    35                  0
                    39                  0
                    42                  1
                    47                  1
                    55                  1
                    61                  1
                    80                  1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If the number of rows in 'CountSoldperMonth' for a particular 'SoldDate' is less than 5 then only the highest count will be marked as 1 in the Target and rest as 0.

Answer (score 1):

In your case , using `groupby` with your rules chain with `apply` if...else

```
df.groupby('SoldDate').CountSoldperMonth.\
     apply(lambda x : x==max(x) if len(x)<=5 else x.isin(sorted(x)[-5:])).astype(int)
Out[346]: 
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    1
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
Name: CountSoldperMonth, dtype: int32
```

Comment: This is giving me 1 as Target for the highest value in 'CountSoldperMonth' for a particular SoldDate and others as 0.